# Is there an FTP server which supports resuming failed downloads?

Tags: file-transfer, ftp

I am looking for an FTP server for my android phone which will allow me to resume a download that has failed. In other words it has to support the `REST` command. Currently I am using (the otherwise excellent) swiFTP, but it doesn't have this feature. I also tried File Expert.

Comment: I'm not sure of your objective and constraints, but would it be possible to use rsync/scp instead of FTP?

Answer (score 1):

Or, if not FTP, and not `rsync`/`scp`, but an SSH server (like [DroidSSHd](http://f-droid.org/forums/topic/droidsshd/), a free/libre SSH server which I could find that would work on my non-rooted Galaxy S with Android 2.2), you could use the simple script [`rpush-into`](https://gitorious.org/rpush-cat/rpush-cat#more) to continue an interrupted transfer.

In [rpush-*](https://gitorious.org/rpush-cat/rpush-cat#more) scripts, I've implemented the file-transfer through SSH with the help of only the basic `cat` and `ls` on the remote side. So that it can be used even if the SSH server on Android doesn't provide `scp`, `sftp`, or `rsync`.

Comment: FISH has also a similar idea to my `rpush-*` scripts: require only the basic Unix utilities, no specialized server program -- <http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8735/4319>. And Emacs TRAMP, too (but the regular TRAMP client didn't work with Android, because it required `stat` which was absent on Android -- <https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs23/+bug/1041474>). Not sure whether either FISH clients or Emacs TRAMP would support resuming partial uploads...